# LaTeX3 RenewDocumentCommand for cite with an optional argument for punctuation

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, natbib, conditionals, latex3

When working with citations there are many distinct ways the citation must be incorporated within the text.  Even when you work exclusively with number formats (this example excludes Author year style citations).

While exclusively using a number reporting system, two of the most common styles I repeatedly have to change between include

- the in-line, in-sentence, square bracket enclosed, numbers inside the sentence punctuation (IEEE)
- and the space gobbled superscript numbers outside the punctuation

natbib does a good job of letting me switch between these formats exceptionally quickly, and redirect the formatting to a different bst file.

Unfortunately, I have to go through my text manually and move the punctuation to the other side of the reference.

I keep having to do this since collaborators just can't make up their minds, and it finally has driven me to the point where I just want to write a modified version of the cite command where, if there is punctuation with the reference, I just add it as an argument to be globally assigned a position of before or after the reference itself.

In my complete document (only major exception is it includes bibunits) this compiles fine, but it doesn't recognize the [.] as an argument, it just appends it after the citation.  The following MWE will fail to compile completely, but I haven't been able to identify whether it fails because of a missing package, or because of a problem with my `LaTeX3` command.

I have written many `DeclareDocumentCommand`s before, with no problems having `m+ o` arguments, so I don't know quite why the `RenewDocumentCommand` fails.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}  % can exclude etoolbox. xpatch loads it anyway, since xpatch extends etoolbox
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[numbers,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\global\let\originalcite\cite
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{ m+ o }
{
    % two arguments, the citation string, and an optional argument of the punctuation
    \tl_if_blank:VTF{#2}{\originalcite{#1}}%
    {%
        {\gobble}{#2}{\originalcite{#1}}
    }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

The original cite command \originalcite{goossens93}.

Depending on the style I work with I will have to change everything manually to:  The original cite command.\originalcite{goossens93}

But if I can create a macro, I only have to add a toggle, or change the order manually.  Of course increasing the complexity of the logic is possible to work for different types of punctuation, but this is a MWE after all.  The modified cite command I am trying to produce is \cite{goossens93}[.]


\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

In my efforts to simplify the problem I tried to remove `bibunits` to make it easier for others to compile.  Turns out `bibunits` was my initial culprit in causing literal typesetting of what should have been an argument.  Updated MWE below using solution recommendation.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[numbers,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\defaultbibliographystyle{plainnat}
\defaultbibliography{\jobname}

\LetLtxMacro\originalcite\cite

\ExplSyntaxOn % just not to worry about spaces and end-of-lines
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{ m o }
 {
  \IfValueT { #2 }{ \unskip #2 }
  \originalcite { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}
The original cite command \originalcite{goossens93}.

Depending on the style I work with I will have to change everything 
manually to:  The original cite command.\originalcite{goossens93}

But if I can create a macro, I only have to add a toggle, or change 
the order manually.  Of course increasing the complexity of the logic 
is possible to work for different types of punctuation, but this is 
a MWE after all.  The modified cite command I am trying to produce 
is \cite{goossens93}[.]
\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, you have you insert the code between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: @JagathAR I originally left it out because the punctuation may be interpreted incorrectly by expl3, but only intermittently do I get a problem with the underscores and colons when the Syntax tags are there or not.

Comment: As usual, when other packages are loaded, timing of redefinitions may be crucial. I added a workaround for `bibunits`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read correctly your question, you want that the trailing optional argument is printed before the superscript.

1. `\tl_if_blank:VTF` is the wrong function, because the `V` means a variable is expected;
2. `{\gobble}{#2}{\originalcite{#1}}` is meaningless;
3. `m+o` means that the last (optional) argument is “long”, that is, it accepts `\par` in it; it should be read as `m +o`, rather than `m+ o`, but you don't want `\par` in either argument.

Correct solution: do nothing if the optional argument is absent, otherwise “`\unskip`” and print it before the citation. Use `xparse` features for dealing with arguments, rather than low level functions like `\tl_if_blank:nTF`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{expl3} % xparse loads it
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[numbers,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\LetLtxMacro\originalcite\cite

\ExplSyntaxOn % just not to worry about spaces and end-of-lines
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{ m o }
 {
  \IfValueT { #2 }{ \unskip #2 }
  \originalcite { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

The original cite command \originalcite{goossens93}.

Depending on the style I work with I will have to change everything 
manually to:  The original cite command.\originalcite{goossens93}

But if I can create a macro, I only have to add a toggle, or change 
the order manually.  Of course increasing the complexity of the logic 
is possible to work for different types of punctuation, but this is 
a MWE after all.  The modified cite command I am trying to produce 
is \cite{goossens93}[.]

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When `bibunits` is used, the redefinition of `\cite` must go before loading it, because the package in turn redefines `\cite` at the beginning of each `bibunit` environment. Or, more simply, one has to update `\std@cite` to use the redefined `\cite` command.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[numbers,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\defaultbibliographystyle{plainnat}
\defaultbibliography{\jobname}

\ExplSyntaxOn % just not to worry about spaces and end-of-lines
\LetLtxMacro\originalcite\cite
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{ m o }
 {
  \IfValueT { #2 }{ \unskip #2 }
  \originalcite { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% update the command bibunits uses for the original \cite
\makeatletter
\let\std@cite\cite
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
The original cite command \originalcite{goossens93}.

Depending on the style I work with I will have to change everything 
manually to:  The original cite command.\originalcite{goossens93}

But if I can create a macro, I only have to add a toggle, or change 
the order manually.  Of course increasing the complexity of the logic 
is possible to work for different types of punctuation, but this is 
a MWE after all.  The modified cite command I am trying to produce 
is \cite{goossens93}[.]

\putbib

\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Comment: May be give the new `\cite` intelligence to check the next token? That way it could be automatic `\cite{foo}. \cite{foo}, \cite{foo}; etc.`.

Comment: @Manuel Isn't it what `fnpct` does?

Comment: Okey, I didn't know :)

Comment: @egreg Thanks, the point of the question is not necessarily to print the punctuation "after" the reference, its to give me a flexible function where I can define rules to print before or after depending on what the character is.  So eventually there will be character comparisons, but before I could even get that far, I had to get a basic MWE working.  So for your point 2, it may be useless with superscripts but the gobble was there  to destroy the space if I want to control spacing on bracketed references.  point 3, I thought a multiline string of references might have needed `+`, my mistake.

Comment: I have updated my question because your solution doesn't work within `bibunits`, which as it turns out was actually responsible for my original error.  When using `cite` in `bibunits` the renewed macro is ignored.  I tested it with some strings added to `\originalcite{#1} test` but the extra string doesn't appear because the renewed command is not being used.

Comment: @EngBIRD Added the workaround

Comment: Thanks a tonne!!!  What does \std@ mean though?

Comment: @EngBIRD `\std@cite` is the macro `bibunits` uses to store the current meaning of `\cite`. Not a well chosen name, but that's what it is.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution (if I understand the question right):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{letltxmacro}

%\usepackage[numbers,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}% Toggle this line
\usepackage[numbers,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}% Toggle this line

\global\let\originalcite\cite

\makeatletter
\def\cite#1{\Cite{#1}}
\def\Cite#1{\@ifnextchar[{\@Cite#1}{\@Cite#1[]}}
\def\@Cite#1[#2]{\ifNAT@super\unskip#2\originalcite{#1}\else\originalcite{#1}\unskip#2\fi}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

The original cite command \originalcite{goossens93}.

Depending on the style I work with I will have to change everything
manually to:  The original cite command.\originalcite{goossens93}

But if I can create a macro, I only have to add a toggle, or change the
order manually.  Of course increasing the complexity of the logic is
possible to work for different types of punctuation, but this is a MWE
after all.  The modified cite command I am trying to produce is
\cite{goossens93}[.]


\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is an alternative to the MWE above, but I approached it with epl3 type syntax because I need to be able to add numerous levels of if statements to check for commas vs periods, and document Booleans for square brackets vs superscripts.  I am not sure if your compact one-liner will be flexible enough for me.